# How to change checked next radio button by click button?

Tags: javascript

```
1:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio1" checked />
<br>
2:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio2" />
<br>
3:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio3" />
<br>
4:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio4" />
<br>
5:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio5" />
<br>
<button class="button">
click
</button>
```

[**fiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/v7webjdx/)

The code does not working!

By clicking the button, change checked the next radio button.

Comment: Change to what? To not checked? To the next radio button?

Comment: I just tested your fiddle link and its working.When button gets clicked option 1 gets checked.make sure that  jquery library is included.

Comment: Change checked the next radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't link jquery to your code. Add jquery then it should work.

Demo:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
    var i = $('input[name=option]:checked').val();
    var index = parseInt(i) + 1;
    if (index > $('input[name=option]').length) index = 1;
    $('.radio' + index).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio1" value="1" checked />
<br>
2:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio2" value="2"/>
<br>
3:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio3" value="3"/>
<br>
4:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio4" value="4"/>
<br>
5:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio5" value="5"/>
<br>
<button class="button">
click
</button>
```

Comment: Your script just check the first radio button when click button. The above snippet worked. Please check again.

Comment: can you explain what will happen when the button clicked?

Comment: If click the button ( class="button" ) then change checked the next radio button

Comment: Yes. Just replace 5 with `$('input[name=option]').length` then it will work for any amounth. I have editted the snippet for that. This is working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L5pkynwd/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
        $('.radio1').prop('checked', false); 
      // or
        $('.radio2').prop('checked', true);
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    1:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio1" checked />
    <br>
    2:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio2" />
    <br>
    3:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio3" />
    <br>
    4:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio4" />
    <br>
    5:<input type="radio" name="option" class="radio5" />
    <br>
    <button class="button">
    click
    </button>
```

Comment: I want all the buttons to work.
But your code only works with two buttons!